# Need assistance in ajax spinner displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax request which actually looks like this.

```
$loading = $("#loadingDiv")
function loadBuildList() {
    $.ajax({
    async:true,
    url:"ajax_test.php",
    beforeSend : function() { $loading.show(); },
    success : function() { $loading.hide() }
    });
}
```

Now, I need to display a spinner image while the ajax is running, Also my code is not supposed to execute further until the ajax's execution is over. If I make `async:false` I will not be able to load the spinner. If I make `async:true` I will not be able to wait till ajax execution is over.

Below is how I am calling the function `loadBuildList`

```
...
//$loading.show(); // this I will use when aync : false
loadBuildList()
//$loading.hide();
...
```

How can I handle such situation? Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See linked - it explains how to restructure/rethink your design.

Comment: If you need to make an original async call synchronous so your code would work, you're coding it wrong. You can either place the code to be executed in the success callback or use Promises (recommended).

Comment: put spinner image inside loadingDiv, $loading.hide() in always callback bcz if any error happened spinner will continue to show, return response from success callback.

Comment: @shi *"return response from success callback"* no.  It's too late to "return response".   See linked possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never use `async:false`**, or you'll stop the whole execution thread until it has got a response.

Everything that needs to be run after an async execution, in this case `$.ajax` needs to be written inside the callback. That is inside success for JQuery `$.ajax`.

```
$loading = $("#loadingDiv")
function loadBuildList() {
    $.ajax({
    async:true,
    url:"ajax_test.php",
    beforeSend : function() { $loading.show(); },
    success : function() { 
      $loading.hide();
      // Stuff after $.ajax goes here.
    },
    fail: function() {
      // Or here.
    }
    });
}
```

You should also have a read at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try this out.

Comment: @SurajSun if you are doing this, you should also read over http://callbackhell.com/ , and try avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of code snippet you have provided it seems there is no need to use `beforeSend` as you just have one call on the page. You can do it following way.

```
$loading = $("#loadingDiv");

function loadBuildList() {
    $loading.show(); // Show spinner before AJAX call
    $.ajax({
        async:true,
        url:"ajax_test.php",
        // beforeSend : function() {  },
        success : function() { $loading.hide() }
    });
}
```

You can still try to make it as mentioned by @zurfyx but usually this practice is followed when you need something centralized and not for individual AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

Handling the spinner is fine with `.complete` (so picks up both success and error):

```
function loadBuildList() {
    var loading = $("#loadingDiv")
    loading.show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax_test.php",
        complete : function() { loading.hide() }
    });
}
```

However, this comment is more interesting:

> my code is not supposed to execute further

It's not that you don't want to execute further, it's that you want to continue execution when the ajax call has completed.

You can do this by returning the $.ajax object, which is a `promise`.  With the promise, you can then add chain calls in your own code.  This is similar to using a callback parameter, but generally more flexible:

```
function loadBuildList() {
    return $.ajax({
    ...
}

// calling code
loadBuildList().done(function() {
    // code to run when the list has loaded
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try this.